# How to retrieve any .csv or .txt files from a FTP server to local directory?

Tags: powershell, ftp

I am trying to create one script in order to download any .txt or .csv files in a FTP server.

How can i do for writing one kind of mention ".txt", "*.txt" etc in this POWERSHELL command ?

I used a pipeline etc without results.

Here's below my POWERSHELL code which works for a file:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ftp://login:password@server/PhotosPuky_2023-10-25-16-36.txt -OutFile "G:\service INFORMATIQUE 5IVE\BIKE OFFICE\IMPORT_FICHIERS\Matrices internes\MACROS_ESTEVEZ\V5\PhotosPuky_2023-10-25-16-36.txt"
```

Like that, it works but for any ".txt" files, i don't know how to do.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` has _no_ support for listing directories via FTP and therefore no support for discovering files via _wildcard patterns_ (and in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_ it doesn't support FTP at all).
[Third-party modules](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=ftp) are available, and direct use of .NET APIs or the [WinSCP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP) library is also an option, as shown in 
the linked duplicate.